# Exception: variable does not exist in rstan:failed to create the sampler

Tags: sampling, rstan

I`ve tried finding a similar error to mine on the site but I cannot find anything. I am not sure what am I doing wrong because I keep getting the below error message. I would greatly appreciate it if somebody could explain why do I keep getting an error.TIA

error message:
Error in new_CppObject_xp(fields$.module, fields$.pointer, ...) : 
  Exception: variable does not exist; processing stage=data initialization; variable name=j; base type=int  (in 'model32487fbf6c2c_production' at line 2)

failed to create the sampler; sampling not done

```
Rcode
```

```html
library(rstan)




 dat1 <- list(a1=0, b1= 1, a2 =0.1, b2 =0.5, j <-6, n <-c(3,7,4,8,5,9), x <-c(10,33,3,39,5,50))
 
 fit1 <- stan(file = "production.stan", data = dat1, chains = 3, iter = 1000,)
 
 print(fit1)
```

Stan code

```js
data {
  int < lower = 0 > j;
  int x[j];
  int n[j];
  real a1;
  real b1;
  real a2;
  real b2;
}

parameters {
  real < lower = 0 > lambda[j];
  real < lower = 0 > sigma;
  real mu;
}
transformed parameters {
  real lambdanew1 = lambda[1]. / n[1];
  real lambdanew2 = lambda[2]. / n[2];
  real lambdanew3 = lambda[3]. / n[3];
  real lambdanew4 = lambda[4]. / n[4];
  real lambdanew5 = lambda[5]. / n[5];
  real lambdanew6 = lambda[6]. / n[6];
}
model {
  target += poisson_lpmf(x[1] | lambda[1]);
  target += poisson_lpmf(x[2] | lambda[2]);
  target += poisson_lpmf(x[3] | lambda[3]);
  target += poisson_lpmf(x[4] | lambda[4]);
  target += poisson_lpmf(x[5] | lambda[5]);
  target += poisson_lpmf(x[6] | lambda[6]);
  target += lognormal_lpdf(lambdanew1 | mu, sigma);
  target += lognormal_lpdf(lambdanew2 | mu, sigma);
  target += lognormal_lpdf(lambdanew3 | mu, sigma);
  target += lognormal_lpdf(lambdanew4 | mu, sigma);
  target += lognormal_lpdf(lambdanew5 | mu, sigma);
  target += lognormal_lpdf(lambdanew6 | mu, sigma);
  target += uniform_lpdf(mu | a1, b1);
  target += uniform_lpdf(sigma | a2, b2);
}
```

Comment: It means that your dat1 file does not contain j. You need to use = in a list(), not <-

Comment: Also your Stan code with throw another error because you have a space between . and /

Comment: @ssp3nc3r thank you for your response and help. It worked